# Session cookie security

Tags: cookies, session-management

I am creating a small login system. It looks like the standard username/pwd and user can either log or register.

If they pass (authenticate), I create a session cookie that will be sent with the header every time, so that the user is not logging in every-time.

But I am pondering this scenario. The cookie is sent in the header, so it is visible for eaves droppers.

- Would they be able to send a request to the site setting a header.session.id cookie ?

In this silly case any hacker could hijack someone else's session by sniffing request headers in a net.

You can not do this in the browser URL-bar but on the console using fetch, or NodeJS request or lwp-request, python requests etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The cookie is sent in the header, so it is visible for eaves droppers.

It is not visible for eavesdroppers on the network if the connection is encrypted, i.e. HTTPS is used. With HTTPS not only the request body is encrypted but also the request header.

> ...  but on the console using fetch ...

Access to the browser console requires access to the computer, i.e. the attacker already needs to have compromised the system.

> ... , or NodeJS request or lwp-request, python requests etc. ...

Using a HTTP client written in such languages does not provide access to the existing session cookie the user has inside the browser. Assuming properly designed session cookies, it is possible to programmatically login using the correct credentials and getting a new session cookie, specific for this newly logged in session. Of course knowing the correct credentials requires that the attacker already has compromised the account.

Comment: thank you, i always forget what is not encrypted in https. I know that IPs source and dest are not, and some other details...sorry that i can not upvote score less than 15. will likely accept if no better answer is given.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy though, to try a couple of millions session ids (with the software I mentioned) and get information from users? Seems extremely possible to me given the long expiration dates + number of users of some apps...

Comment: @MahNeh: Assuming proper session cookies which contain sufficient randomness such a brute force is not feasible. Even when assuming that one could try 100.000 session ids in a second (probably unrealistic) it would take many years to  brute force even 6 bytes (48 bit - not the same as 8 alphanumeric characters!) of randomness.

Comment: @MahNeh if an attacker can do that, your session tokens are waaaaaaaaay too weak. Suppose you're using a 128-bit (entropy, not necessarily length) token, a common strength. Further suppose that not just one person, but _every user_, is attacking it (birthday attack). "A couple millions" is 2^21. You'd need roughly 2^53 users - about 8 quadrillion, or roughly a million times as many people as exist on the planet - all attacking each other millions of times - before, statistically, one would ever find another's session. But if that's too risky, you can use 256 bits of entropy instead.

Comment: Ok once it is done i would be glad to see if either of you can crack it. It's an extremely small app to chat with friends (i am not a programmer). @CBHacking

Comment: 2^128 times to get all possible combinations. Fine. The chance is the number of session ids times that number. If there are 2^64 created session IDs, then the chance to guess one is 2^(-64). I am not sure how many a powerful computer could try per second..@CBHacking

Comment: @MahNeh Well, first I'm curious where you plan to find two billion sessions for every human being alive, what database you're planning to store them in, and how long your system plans to spend generating them. But suppose they do exist anyhow, and you want to guess one. Say you have a gigabit connection, and a minimal valid request is 50 bytes (400 bits). That's 2.5 million attempts per second, max. At that rate, you can try 2^64 possibilities in a mere 233817 years. Better get going!

Comment: Yes I was rounding up by billions..Thanks for the calculation @CBHacking. Very interesting. I will ask for help. Actually, I don't want to do any of that, but I don't want to accept procedures without some reasoning. This is quite enlightening too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies